# how to send custom Actionfilter to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, action-filter

I have never worked with actionfilter before so i dont really understand how to do it. I have created the controller which i think will work, but now i want to my _ViewStart.cshtml to call this controller and dont know how to do it, i dont really know if my controller is right:

```
public class CoActionFilter : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public string CompanyFilter(ResultExecutedContext filterContext, Models.DynCss Cssdata, int id)
    {
        var service = ServiceFactory.Instance.CreateTemplateService();
        var data = service.GetEntry(id);
        var OverdriveCss = new Models.DynCss
        {
            GetAllTempData = data,
            BGColor = Cssdata.GetAllTempData.TempBG,
            HeadColor = Cssdata.GetAllTempData.TempHeader,
            LayColor = Cssdata.GetAllTempData.TempLayout,
            TextColor = Cssdata.GetAllTempData.TempText,
            FootColor = Cssdata.GetAllTempData.TempFooter
        };
        string templateContent = File.ReadAllText("Content/Site.css");
        return Razor.Parse(templateContent, OverdriveCss);
    }
}
```

ps: The _Viewstart.cshtml doesnt have a controller or a model and this is why i need to use actionfilter. And i want this controller to be called inside: if (Request.IsAuthenticated)

Comment: What do you mean by saying "Controller" in your question and how it (and _Viewstart.cshtml) relates to code sample?

Comment: @Dima in my viewstart im checking  if (Request.IsAuthenticated, its going to overdrive some attributes css by using razor.parse, and because i cant use razor.parse in _viewstart, and that _viewstart doesnt have a controller or a model, i need to use actionfilter so i can use razor.parse